# How to update and upsert multiple documents in MongoDB in django

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I want to upsert multiple documents with a single query in mongodb like we can do in mysql with duplicate key update.

I have already tried the solution for upserting each doc through iteration via

```
db.collection.update_one({'hotel_id': hotel_doc['hotel_id']},
                               {'$set': {**hotel_doc, **{'ut': ct}}, '$setOnInsert': {'ct': ct}}, upsert=True)
```

Please help

my collection looks like this

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5eea01d030b03c07d0352ac9"),
  "hotel_id": "200701181651218971",
  "hotel_status": true,
  "country_id": "IN",
  "city_id": "XCR",
  "star_rating": "5",
  "chain_code": "TJ",
  "property_type": "CHAIN",
  "location": {
    "n": "Coorg",
    "crds": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        75.6589525123024,
        12.3781178180329
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using PyMongo driver, could you confirm that? Could you also show how does your collection looks like and what you want to update to?

Comment: Yes i'm using pymongo3.10, i have updated my collection in desc. If the doc is already present i can update location property_type, star_rating, hotel_status

Comment: This part `{'$set': {**hotel_doc, **{'ut': ct}}, '$setOnInsert': {'ct': ct}}` is unclear, could you explain more? And how should your updated collection look like in both the scenario `set` as well as `setOnInsert`?